# Matching sets of coordinates

Tags: matching, coordinate-systems

I have a set of points (500 points), each has its own coordinate. These points are represented by two different 2-D coordinate systems (e.g., (X, Y) and (x, y)). I have a list of 500 (X,Y)-type of coordinates and 500 (x,y)-type of coordinates. My goal is to match them pairwise. There should be 1-1 mapping between the two sets. I can also convert a distance from one coordinate system to the other.

I am thinking about using pairwise distances as a means to match. Please let me know if there is a simple way to do that. Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear how exactly you want to match each pair of coordinates, just that you want to use pairwise distances. Do you want to minimize pairwise distance, maximize pairwise distance, minimize distance variance, minimize range of distances, etc.? Also how do the two 2D coordinate systems differ?

Comment: The two coordinate systems differ by the origins and units (1 unit in (X,Y) = n units in (x,y)). Each coordinate system contains the same number of points, and there should be only one way to match them. Maybe it would be easier to understand if I say that I have a graph that was drawn in two coordinate systems. Thank you!